# Active directory memberof atributo con c#

Tags: c#, ldap

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy intentando extraer y modificar datos de un usuario en active directory usando DirectoryServices.

El problema está en querer quitarle la membresías de los grupos a un usuario. Para traer las membresias no hay problema realizo lo siguiente:

```
string membrecias = string.Empty;
foreach (object memberOf in result.Properties["memberOf"])
{
    membrecias += " Member Of..........: " + memberOf.ToString() + "\n";
}
lblmembrecias.Text = membrecias;
```

El problema es, como podría hacer para ir sacándoselas?

Aguardo comentarios, muchas gracias desde ya!

Comment: Empezamos por el principio, eres el administrador del AD o tienes lo permisos necesarios para hacer cambios?

Comment: Buenos días, Manny. si, tengo los permisos. es más, demás cambios ya los puedo realizar correctamente, habilitar/deshabilitar usuarios y esas cosas. Este es el único cambio que me faltaría realizar. El de sacar membrecías

Comment: MemberOf no se puede configurar. Para hacer que un objeto sea miembro o no de un grupo, debe establecer el atributo de miembro del grupo para incluir el objeto.

Comment: no entendi, como sería?